# Hardware platform for audio processing

Tags: audio, hardware, arduino, microcontroller

I want to build some kind of audio processing unit. I would connect some microphones to it (like those in phones, not the big ones for singers). I have some experience with reading the raw audio data in Android, that's an abstraction level I can handle. Everything that gets more low level is a bit hairy for me. (Raw means here that I read integers from a buffer.)

Is there a hardware platform that allows me to easily connect microphones and read the raw audio data? And I want to connect it to a computer over USB to transfer the raw audio data. I think the further processing would happen on the computer, like [Fourier transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), etc.

I have heard about Arduino, does it provide a good abstaction level for that? What platforms could I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason to use an Arduino for this, a standard PC sound card works just fine!  What you are asking for is exactly how it works.  You can capture audio, and read sampled values from the buffer.

Comment: Ok, are there extern soundcards maybe? I want it to be a portable device that I can connect to a laptop.

Comment: Or maybe hubs for several microphones to connect to the soundcard? But I want to tread the mics seperatly, maybe that does not work so easily.

Comment: @Puckl, Yes, by the thousands, with as many inputs as you could possibly want.  Plus, why not just use the one built into your laptop?

Comment: I'm not sure what audio quality you're looking for.  If you need something cheap and don't care about phasing, you can buy a whole box of USB sound interfaces for about $1 each.  If you want high quality, studio interfaces are readily available.  http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/US1800/

Comment: Thanks, extern soundcards with several inputs, thats it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with Arduino (at least, with the 8-bit boards) is that they do not have any kind of DACs, so you can not do much. Also the computation power is not enough for real-time audio processing, unless you want to do some sort of old-style music, like in old game systems.

This situation can change with the brand-new Arduino Due, which includes a 32-bit ARM processor. Here you have some DACs and the computation power should be enough to do some nice audio processing. The inconvenient is that this board is really new and the development tools are still unstable. Think that most Arduino boards bring an AVR micro controller, whilst this Arduino Due features an ARM processor. The architecture is completely different.

I would like to recommend you some boards. If you want to do some audio processing, I think it is good to have a board with jack connectors (input/output), SD Card (to read some audio files), and maybe a screen to do some sort visualization (i.e. graphic bars) with audio signals.

- A first option: Raspberry Pi. It is open hardware (as much as possible... because ARM-manufacturers protect their chips with patents) cheap, and the community do lots of projects. I think it is like Arduino, but with a much powerful architecture.
- mikroElektronika has some nice [Multimedia boards](http://www.mikroe.com/mikromedia/pic32/). They provide them in several versions (i.e. AVR, PIC, ARM, ...) so you can select any architecture you like, but peripherals are all the same (sound chip, TFT, WIFI, ...). They also provide compilers, libraries and documentation. This is a not very big company, so I think they care about customers and you will get good technical support.

If you do not like any of these, I can propose some other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the new headphones for PCs that include microphone, are conected via USB, that means that each one that you connect to a PC is a sound itself.